# How to execute a piece of JavaScript code using Chrome developer tools

Tags: javascript, browser, developer-tools

I use Google Chrome and its developer tools like '**Inspect element**' to check performance of my web pages. I know that its Developer tool '`Console`' can be used to execute JavaScript.

I was just saving my one interested web page on my Delicious web account and I noticed that all that information it needs goes through **`JavaScript`**, So I just tried to put that code on my JS Console so that I can see the whole background process, but it failed. Can anyone please tell me how should I work with it, because I know this can be done.

The things I am seeing
[image: When I clicked the bookmark]

The code you will need to save as your bookmark

```
javascript:(function(e,t)%7Bvar n=e.document;setTimeout(function()%7Bfunction a(e)%7Bif(e.data==="destroy_bookmarklet")%7Bvar r=n.getElementById(t);if(r)%7Bn.body.removeChild(r);r=null%7D%7D%7Dvar t="DELI_bookmarklet_iframe",r=n.getElementById(t);if(r)%7Breturn%7Dvar i="https://delicious.com/save?",s=n.createElement("iframe");s.id=t;s.src=i+"url="+encodeURIComponent(e.location.href)+"&title="+encodeURIComponent(n.title)+"&note="+encodeURIComponent(""+(e.getSelection?e.getSelection():n.getSelection?n.getSelection():n.selection.createRange().text))+"&v=1.1";s.style.position="fixed";s.style.top="0";s.style.left="0";s.style.height="100%25";s.style.width="100%25";s.style.zIndex="16777270";s.style.border="none";s.style.visibility="hidden";s.onload=function(){this.style.visibility="visible"};n.body.appendChild(s);var o=e.addEventListener?"addEventListener":"attachEvent";var u=o=="attachEvent"?"onmessage":"message";e[o](u,a,false)},1)})(window)
```

**Details:** I've an account on delicious.com which provides me a service to save my interested web links. for example If I am visiting a Stackoverflow question page and I like the question I just need to click on the bookmark(I've provided you the URL above), I am wondering how it fetches its parent page and saves it in their database, How it can be done using just javascript, I always noticed bookmarks with only web addresses but this one contains javascript code, Can anyone please tell me how it works, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you tried to execute is a `JavaScript pseudo-scheme`. Note the `javascript:` part at the beginning. Doesn't it sound familiar with other schemes like `http:`, `https:`, `ftp:`?

It would be executed in the URL, not in the Console. In other words, you use `JavaScript pseudo-scheme` to execute a piece of JavaScript code, **in the address bar of the browser**.

To execute it in Console, you have to do two things:

1. Remove `javascript:` scheme
2. Because it's supposed to be executed in the URL, it's URL encoded. You have to decode it first. See that `%7B`? It represents `{`. Console won't recognize it, till it's decoded to the original character.

Comment: Note that the `javascript:` isn't hurting anything in the console, because it's treated as a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) (though it is totally unnecessary). The URL encoding, as you say, is definitely causing the breakage.